# Installing Bootstrap 4 Beta with Bower

Tags: json, twitter-bootstrap, bower, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to install the latest version of Bootstrap 4 Beta using bower.

Using this command:

```
bower install bootstrap#v4.0.0-beta
```

Results in:

```
no matches found: bootstrap#v4.0.0-beta
```

Is there anything I'm doing wrong?

My **bower.json** looks as follows:

```
{
"name": "bootstrap-starter",
"homepage": "https://github.com/marcuschristiansen/bootstrap-starter",
"authors": [
"Marcus Christiansen <christiansen.marcus@gmail.com>"
],
"description": "All dependencies for the bootstrap starter theme",
"main": "",
"license": "MIT",
"ignore": [
  "**/.*",
  "node_modules",
  "bower_components",
  "test",
  "tests"
],
"dependencies": {
  "jquery": "~2.2.3",
  "normalize-scss": "git@github.com:JohnAlbin/normalizescss.git#^4.1.0",
  "bootstrap": "4.0",
  "font-awesome": "git@github.com:FortAwesome/Font-Awesome.git",
  "bourbon": "^4.2.7",
  "neat": "^1.8.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I just installed Bootstrap 4 Beta with the same command: `bower install bootstrap#v4.0.0-beta` with npm version 5.3.0 and Bower 1.8.0.

Have you tried updating npm and Bower and running the same install command?

Comment: I get an error saying "bower EINVRES .. failed with 410"

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap drops bower support:

See: http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/#beta-2-changes

```
Dropped Bower support as the package manager has been deprecated for alternatives (e.g., Yarn or npm).
```